# How to reshape my Python dataframe to accomidate 'PowerBI' Venn Diagram?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here my objective is to reshape my panda's data frame and load new data frame into PowerBI and use PowerBI Veen diagram.

Venn Diagram needs a specific format and little tricky to get that via pandas. I can get the desired dataset via "npwhere" function but seems like very intensive and a lot of code.

Is there any different way I achieve my desired output?

My dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3','A4','A5'],
                'Social': ['0', '0', '2', '3','2', '3'],
                  'Math': ['0', '1', '2', '3','2', '3'],
                   'Science': ['0', '0', '4', '3','2', '3'],
                   'Computers':['0', '0', '0', '0','2', '3']})

df1
```

My desired dataset would be like below:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Number_of_Students': ['1', '1', '2', '2'],
                'Social': ['NO', 'NO', 'Yes', 'Yes'],
                  'Math': ['NO', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes'],
                   'Science': ['NO', 'NO', 'Yes', 'Yes'],
                   'Computers':['NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'Yes']})

df2
```

Explanation of the output:
In the end result, the number of occurrences or summarize Names into numbers
In this example

- Social, Math, Science, Computer '0' = 1 student
- Social = 0, Math is more than 0, Science, and computer is more than 0
  = 1 student
- Social, Math, Science is more than 0 and computer is 0 = 2 students
- Social, Math, Science, and Computer is more than 0 = 2 students

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with

```
df1.loc[:,'Social':]=df1.loc[:,'Social':].ne('0').replace({False:'NO',True:'Yes'})

df=df1.groupby(df1.columns[1:].tolist()).Name.count().reset_index()
df
  Social Math Science Computers  Name
0     NO   NO      NO        NO     1
1     NO  Yes      NO        NO     1
2    Yes  Yes     Yes        NO     2
3    Yes  Yes     Yes       Yes     2
```